# Mapping array into object keyed by array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapreduce

I need to be able to remove object from object based on array values.

I have a base object:

```
   const obj = {
      one: {
        selected: undefined,
      }, 
      two: {
        selected: undefined,
      },
      three: {
        selected: undefined,
      }
    };
```

Example array is:

```
const arr = ['one', 'two'];
```

My attempt at doing this:

```
const mappedObj = arr.map(val => {
  if (obj[val]) {
    return ({
      [val]: {
        selected: true
      },
    });
  }

  return false;
})
```

I need it to be:

```
object: {
  one: {
    selected: true,
  },
  two: {
   selected: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: How is it determined that `one.selected` is true and `two.selected` is false as per your expected result?

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, it should be true

Answer (score 1):

You could map single objects and assign them to a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for the array.

```js
var object = { one: { selected: undefined, foo: 42 }, two: { selected: undefined }, three: { selected: undefined } },
    array = ['one', 'two'],
    result = Object.assign(
        ...array.map(k => ({ [k]: Object.assign({}, object[k], { selected: true }) }))
    );
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `selected` is not set to `true`

Comment: I'd also suggest just in case: `{ ...obj[k], selected: true }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `reduce` on `arr` array:

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (obj[key]) {
    acc[key] = { ...obj[key], selected: true };
  }
  return acc
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `forEach()` loop:

```js
const obj = {
      one: {
        selected: undefined,
      }, 
      two: {
        selected: undefined,
      },
      three: {
        selected: undefined,
      }
    };

const arr = ['one', 'two'];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => obj[key].selected = arr.includes(key));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "reduce" instead of "map":

```
const obj = {
      one: {
        selected: undefined,
      }, 
      two: {
        selected: undefined,
      },
      three: {
        selected: undefined,
      }
    };
const arr = ['one', 'two'];
const mappedObj = arr.reduce((acm, val) => { 
    if (val in obj) { 
      acm[val] = { selected: true };
    }
    return acm;
  }, 
  {}
);
```

result:

```
{ one: { selected: true }, two: { selected: true } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
      one: {
        selected: undefined,
      }, 
      two: {
        selected: undefined,
      },
      three: {
        selected: undefined,
      }
    };

const arr = ['one', 'two'];

Object.keys(obj).map((item) => { 
       if(arr.includes(item)){
         obj[item].selected = true
       } else { 
        delete obj[item]
       }
     })

 console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one line `reduce()`

```js
const obj = {
      one: {
        selected: undefined,
      }, 
      two: {
        selected: undefined,
      },
      three: {
        selected: undefined,
      }
    };



const arr = ['one', 'two'];



const res = 
   arr.reduce((a,c) => (obj[c] && (a[c]= Object.assign({}, obj[c], {selected:true})),a),{});
 

console.log(res)
```